# Return an individual value from GET api response

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm trying to return individual values from an API response to dynamically add the results to my page.
Here is the full response:

```
{
    "data": {
      "timelines": [
          {
              "timestep": "current",
              "endTime": "2022-06-11T05:55:00Z",
              "startTime": "2022-06-11T05:55:00Z",
              "intervals": [
                {
                    "startTime": "2022-06-11T05:55:00Z",
                    "values": {
                       "grassIndex": 5,
                       "treeIndex": 0,
                       "weedIndex": 0
                }
            }
          ]
        }
     ]
   }
 }
```

I'm specifically trying to return the individual grassIndex value. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: Would be easier to read if indented properly, but here's a guess:  `result.data.timelines[0].intervals[0].values.grassIndex`

Comment: const grassIndex = JSON.parse(`{
"data": {
"timelines": [
{
"timestep": "current",
"endTime": "2022-06-11T05:55:00Z",
"startTime": "2022-06-11T05:55:00Z",
"intervals": [
{
"startTime": "2022-06-11T05:55:00Z",
"values": {
"grassIndex": 5,
"treeIndex": 0,
"weedIndex": 0
}
}
]
}
]
}
}`).data.timelines[0].intervals[0].values.grassIndex

Comment: thank you... i'm still very new to this but these responses were very helpful. I apologize if my question wasnt 'well researched' and/or is unclear. thanks again